# UIToolBar left/right side button text

Tags: iphone, ios4, human-computer-interface, hig

Apple's "human interface guidelines" is clear about which side (left or right) you should place certain tool-bar buttons:  CANCEL (left).... and.... DONE (right).

Which side (left or right) should other buttons go on?

```
ADD and DONE
EDIT and SAVE
EDIT and ADD
SORT and SEARCH
SORT DIRECTION and SORT FIELD
CANCEL ADD
```

Comment: I'm not here to play foolish "point games".  I only want to give/get help from those that WANT to give/get help.  Not "only if you pay me with points".   StackOverFlow needs a way to block annoying people like middaparka who always "responds" with non-responses like "read the manual" and "give me more points".  And he could block me.   Problem instantly solved for both of us... and everyone that has to waste time reading this.

Answer (score 2):

This is by no means an answer, just an opinion.. i wouldve commented it but for some reason it wont let me..

From what ive gathered, any thing that take you to a previous state: i.e cancel, back, etc would be on the left side..

anything that take you to a forward state, i.e save, add, done, etc would be on the right side.. now depending on the view, whether a button belongs on the left or right might vary..

for example:

consider a ui table view that contains data.. at the top of this view i dont thing id have anything on the top LEFT (unless this table view is NOT the primary view, in which case i probably would have some sort of back button)
on the top RIGHT i would probably have and edit button that lets me delete something from this table view

upon selecting a specific line i would be directed to another view specific to that piece of data.. at the top LEFT i would have a back button and on the top RIGHT i may have another button with more specific functions that were not available on the previous tableview..

this is by no means an answer just an idea to maybe help clarify your situation..
if you look at the hierarchy of your application, you'l often determine the bast place to provide a certain function and whether it actually belongs there

hope it helps